# Cómo colocar componentes en un BorderLayout con un determinado tamaño

Tags: java, layout, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy tratando de hacer una interfaz gráfica usando `borderlayout`. El problema es que al agregar un componente (en el centro) a el contenedor de ese layout, ese componente se expande ocupando las regiones vacías sobrantes.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo agregar un componente en la región del centro conservando determinado tamaño que yo le indique sin que se expanda.

Comment: Bienvenido al Sitio, podrías poner el código con el que estás trabajando, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Mediante `BorderLayout`, aunque tiene una propiedad `BorderLayout.CENTER`, no lo podes centrar como vos queres. Por lo que entiendo, vos queres que tu componente quede con un tamaño determinado pero con `BorderLayout` no lo vas a lograr.

> If the window is enlarged, the center area gets as much of the
>   available space as possible. The other areas expand only as much as
>   necessary to fill all available space.

Lo que quiere decir, que el componente del centro va a aumentar su tamaño para ocupar el lugar faltante del panel o ventana.

Te dejo la documentació de java respecto a `BorderLayout`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html